# Cannot install packages in MikTex or Texmaker

Tags: packages, installing, texmaker

I'm using MikTex 2.9 and TexMaker, recently installed it on my laptop.

I find myself unable to install packages manually on Miktex, nor can I install them when using the command \usepackage{} (I have the settings on 'install packages on the fly')
Whenever I try this, I get an error message saying:
"Unfortunately, the package titlesec could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log"

My log gives me the following information:

2019-10-01 17:09:39,497+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Timeout was reached
2019-10-01 17:09:39,497+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: code="28", url="https://api2.miktex.org/hello"
2019-10-01 17:09:39,497+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\CurlWebSession.cpp
2019-10-01 17:09:39,497+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 266

Has anyone else experienced this or does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX  SX! Did you try to change the MiKTeX repository?

Comment: No not yet, i'm not sure on how to change the repository. I'm using the "random internet repository" option.

Comment: With MiKTeX console:  `Settings -> Genearl tab -> Change package installation`.